# Rails app running on locahost, but I get connection refused whenever I check the web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jmeter, localhost

I have a rails application that I have been running on port 3000 for weeks without any incident, but I am getting connection refused all of the sudden.

When I start the rails server, I get this output on the console:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.5.2 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Zawgyi")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 717
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
```

My problems started after I ran JMeter to learn about load testing (I was able to run 2 tests, but then it broke). My rails application is running on the linux subsystem for Windows 10 (wsl 2), and I used Apache JMeter 5.4.2.

I also tested a NodeJs application, tried using other ports (e.g. 8080) and I still get connection refused.

I made a curl request to http://localhost:3000/ and it worked just fine, same url on any web browser still gets me connection refused.

Comment: Did your browser automatically append an "s" to the http? That's a good place to start. Make sure you are accessing localhost with `http` except your rails app enforces https

Comment: No, it does not. if I enter the full url in the browser for localhost, I still get connection refused even when the server is apparently running on the console. There's no output on the console if I try to access the root path. I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was and fixed it. It turns out that if I ran a node js application on windows, it worked just fine, so all signs pointed that the problem was actually on wsl2.

I found a very helpful article https://appuals.com/localhost-refused-to-connect/ that guided me, and all I needed to do was restart the LxssManager.

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is connected with WSL

- check the underlying [Linux distribution logs](https://stackify.com/linux-logs/)
- check [Windows logs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) related to networking/WSL

In general running JMeter (or any other tool) on the same physical (or virtual) machine is not recommended as you might face a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when JMeter and your application under test will be struggling for the operating system resources hence results will be not very reliable as it will be hard to say where exactly is the bottleneck. Of course you can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to inspect per-process resources usage but it may also fail to tell the full story.

Another potential issue is that [load testing in scaled-down environments may be an issue itself](http://www.quotium.com/performance/risks-of-testing-performance-in-scaled-down-environments/), you're supposed to be running performance tests in production-like environment. If you have 4 GB of RAM and see that application  can handle 1000 users it doesn't mean that with 8 GB of RAM it will handle 2000 users, the metrics and KPIs cannot be extrapolated like this.

And last but bot the least, you're running your app in "development" mode and I would recommend executing it in ["production" mode instead](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/56)